# Ghostscript gsapi_init_with_args() return -100 in VMS

Tags: api, ghostscript

I invoke `gsdll32.dll`, v9.15 in Windows server 2003 Enterprise SP2 at VMWare 10.
`gsapi_init_with_args()` return `-100`.
But in other VMS system like winserver 2008 R2 it works well.

I find the [VMS doc in GS](http://ghostscript.com/doc/9.15/Use.htm#VMS) but I can't understand it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There are VMs, virtual machines, and there is VMS, aka OpenVMS, the operating system. The doc you found as well as the tag you used, here, is for the operating system. Anyway, I doubt that your problem is related to the VM, but I admit I know nothing about VMWare's implementation of a VM.

Answer (score 1):

As upser 2116290 pointed out, VMS is an operatng system, multiple virtual machines might better be written as VMs. If you are working with Virtual Machines running Windows, the documentation for the VMS operating system won't be any help to you.

Error -100 is 'Fatal error' which doesn't tell you anything useful. Usually this will be preceded by some information on the back channel (the PostScript back channel), you should capture that and read it.

Since Ghostscript is known to work with pretty much any version of Windows my guess would be a configuration error on the non-working system.

NB since you are working with the DLL, please review the AGPL which is the licence Ghostscript uses.

Comment: How to get the postScript back channel infor?

Comment: Its part of the API, you have to register a function to receive the back channel, then you can do what you find simplest with the data.

Comment: The only documentation avahostscript installation (in ghostscript/doc or ghostscript/gs/doc depending on the version) and the code supplied with Ghostscript, which uses the DLL and from which a competent programmer should be able to deduce the usage.